# How do you mock the User service in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using the Google App Engine `testbed` framework to write test cases with mock objects. This is documented [here](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html). I've got my datastore tests working nicely using the mock database (`Testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub`), and this lets my test cases run over a fast, fresh database which is re-initialised for each test case. Now I want to test functionality that depends on the current user.

There is another testbed service called `Testbed.init_user_stub`, which I can activate to get the "fake" user service. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any documentation for this one. I am activating and using it like this:

```
import unittest
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from google.appengine.api import users

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_user_stub()

    def testUser(self):
        u = users.get_current_user()
        self.assertNotEqual(u, None)
```

The problem is that I haven't found any way to tell the "fake" user service to authenticate a "fake" user. So running that test, I (predictably) get

```
AssertionError: None == None
```

meaning the fake user service is telling my app that the current user is not logged in. How can I tell the fake user service to pretend that a user is logged in? Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify the fake user's nickname, email, user_id and whether or not they are an admin. It seems like this would be quite a common thing to want (since you need to test how the app behaves when a) nobody is logged in, b) a user is logged in, and c) an admin is logged in), but googling "init_user_stub" returns almost nothing.

Note: If you want to test the above program, you need to add this to the top:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/PATH/TO/APPENGINE/SDK')
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

and this to the bottom:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well I don't think there is an official way to do it, but I have been reading the source code and I found a "hack" way to do it that is working well so far. (Normally I'd be worried about using undocumented behaviour, but it's a test suite so it only matters if it works on the dev server.)

The dev server figures out the currently logged-in user based on three environment variables:

- USER_EMAIL: The user's email address, *and* the user's nickname.
- USER_ID: The user's unique Google ID (string).
- USER_IS_ADMIN: "0" if the user is non-admin, "1" if the user is an admin.

You can use `os.environ` to set these as you would any other environment variable, and they take immediate effect (*obviously this won't work on the production server*). But you can use them with testbed's user_stub and they will be reset when you deactivate the testbed (which you should do on `tearDown`, so you get a fresh environment for each test case).

Since setting environment variables is a bit unwieldy, I wrote some wrapper functions to package them up:

```
import os

def setCurrentUser(email, user_id, is_admin=False):
    os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = email or ''
    os.environ['USER_ID'] = user_id or ''
    os.environ['USER_IS_ADMIN'] = '1' if is_admin else '0'

def logoutCurrentUser():
    setCurrentUser(None, None)
```

Comment: this is basically the right idea. except that you want to use [`testbed.setup_env()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html#Changing_the_Default_Environment_Variables) instead of `os.environ` directly.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because **this is polluting the environment**. It should be noted that a cleanup is required. This can be done using testbed as @ryan stated.

Answer (score 11):

**Here is what worked for me to simulate a logged in user:**

```
self.testbed.setup_env(USER_EMAIL='usermail@gmail.com',USER_ID='1', USER_IS_ADMIN='0')
self.testbed.init_user_stub()
```

Comment: that works, but it seems testbed.setup_env() has to go before testbed.activate(), otherwise it has no effect.

Comment: @gargc I'm sorry to say that what you've stated is wrong and potentially 'dangerous'. Please see my answer for a demonstration.

Comment: @siebz0r Good call ! By the way, I've just found out why I had to change the order of the calls to make it work. USER_EMAIL and USER_ID are set to an empty string upon activation as part of the default environment (that does not happen with user_is_admin). The solution is to pass `overwrite=True` to setup_env, otherwise any variables already in the environment are [ignored](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py?r=381#328) resulting in get_current_user() being always None.

Comment: This required the `overwrite` parameter for me as noted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10852849/1093087).

Answer (score 10):

In addition to [Bijan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306478/)'s answer:

The actual check in `google.appengine.api.users` looks like this:

```
def is_current_user_admin():
    return (os.environ.get('USER_IS_ADMIN', '0')) == '1'
```

The key is thus to set the environment variable `USER_IS_ADMIN` to `'1'`. This can be done in multiple ways, but do note that you're modifying a global variable and thus this might affect other code. The key is to do a proper cleanup.

One could use the [Mock library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to [patch `os.environ`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-dict), use [`Testbed`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting) or roll their own creative way. I prefer to use `Testbed` as it hints that the hack is appengine related. Mock is not included in Python versions before 3.3 so this adds an extra test dependency.

Extra note: When using the [`unittest` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) I prefer to use [`addCleanup`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup) instead of [`tearDown`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) since cleanups are also called when [`setUp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) fails.

Example test:

```
import unittest

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import testbed


class AdminTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        tb = testbed.Testbed()
        tb.activate()
        # ``setup_env`` takes care of the casing ;-)
        tb.setup_env(user_is_admin='1')
        self.addCleanup(tb.deactivate)

    def test_is_current_user_admin(self):
        self.assertTrue(users.is_current_user_admin())
```

**Note:** `Testbed.setup_env` **should be called after** `Testbed.activate`. `Testbed` takes a snapshot of `os.environ` upon activation, that snapshot is restored upon deactivation. If `Testbed.setup_env` is called before activation the real `os.environ` is modified instead of the temporary instance, thus effectively polluting the environment.

This behaves as it should:

```
>>> import os
>>> from google.appengine.ext import testbed
>>> 
>>> tb = testbed.Testbed()
>>> tb.activate()
>>> tb.setup_env(user_is_admin='1')
>>> assert 'USER_IS_ADMIN' in os.environ
>>> tb.deactivate()
>>> assert 'USER_IS_ADMIN' not in os.environ
>>>
```

This pollutes the environment:

```
>>> import os
>>> from google.appengine.ext import testbed
>>> 
>>> tb = testbed.Testbed()
>>> tb.setup_env(user_is_admin='1')
>>> tb.activate()
>>> assert 'USER_IS_ADMIN' in os.environ
>>> tb.deactivate()
>>> assert 'USER_IS_ADMIN' not in os.environ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple helper functions I created for my tests based on answers here. I stuck them in a `test_helper` module:

```
# tests/test_helper.py
import hashlib

def mock_user(testbed, user_email='test@example.com', is_admin=False):
    user_id = hashlib.md5(user_email).hexdigest()
    is_admin = str(int(is_admin))

    testbed.setup_env(USER_EMAIL=user_email,
                      USER_ID=user_id,
                      USER_IS_ADMIN=is_admin,
                      overwrite=True)
    testbed.init_user_stub()

def mock_admin_user(testbed, user_email='admin@example.com'):
    mock_user(testbed, user_email, True)
```

Sample usage (with [NoseGAE](https://github.com/Trii/NoseGAE)):

```
import unittest

from google.appengine.ext import ndb, testbed
from google.appengine.api import users

from tests.test_helper import mock_user, mock_admin_user

class MockUserTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
        ndb.get_context().clear_cache()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def test_should_mock_user_login(self):
        self.assertIsNone(users.get_current_user())
        self.assertFalse(users.is_current_user_admin())

        mock_user(self.testbed)
        user = users.get_current_user()
        self.assertEqual(user.email(), 'test@example.com')
        self.assertFalse(users.is_current_user_admin())

        mock_admin_user(self.testbed)
        admin = users.get_current_user()
        self.assertEqual(admin.email(), 'admin@example.com')
        self.assertTrue(users.is_current_user_admin())
```