# unittest with @login_required decorator

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, tipfy, werkzeug

I use tipfy & gae for my project.
I write unittests, and I to be confronted with a question: 
How I can test the handler which has @login_required decorator?

```
class TestHandler(unittest.TestCase): 
    def setUp(self): 
        self.app = App(rules=rules, config=config, debug=True) 
        self.client = self.app.get_test_client() 
    def test_my_handler(self): 
        r = self.client.post('/service') 
        # hardworking 
        self.assertTrue(r.status_code == 200)
```

How a can set 'self.auth.user' for current handler('/service')

Regards & thanks & sorry for my english )

Oleg

Comment: It's probably too late but I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16144793/394647