# Google App Engine set up a user when using testbed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testbed

I'm using the GAE [testbed](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html) service and when I run `users.get_current_user()` I get `None` i.e.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine") # for Mac OS X
>>> from google.appengine.api import users
>>> from google.appengine.ext import testbed
>>> testbed = testbed.Testbed()
>>> testbed.activate()
>>> testbed.init_user_stub()
>>> users.get_current_user() == None
True
```

This is the expected result. However, I'd like to log in a fake user when running some of my unit tests.

If it's possible (and I expect it would be), how can one log a user in when running `testbed` from the command line so that `get_current_user()` returns an actual user?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To simulate a sign in of an admin user, you can call anywhere in your test function:

```
self.testbed.setup_env(
    USER_EMAIL = 'test@example.com',
    USER_ID = '123',
    USER_IS_ADMIN = '1',
    overwrite = True)
```

Note that you need to use the `overwrite=True` parameter!

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation the following worked for me:

```
>>> os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = 'a@b.c'
>>> os.environ['USER_ID'] = '123'
>>> users.get_current_user()
users.User(email='a@b.c',_user_id='123')
```

I hope this is a good solution, and this answer helps the next person to run into this issue.

#### EDIT: Related variables

To avoid  `/google/appengine/api/users.py:115 - AssertionError: assert _auth_domain`

```
>>> os.environ['AUTH_DOMAIN'] = 'testbed'
```

Per Elliot de Vries comment, for an administrative user:

```
>>> os.environ['USER_IS_ADMIN'] = '1'
```

Comment: Another useful one: os.environ['USER_IS_ADMIN'] = '1'

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have any recommendations for examples of unit tests? I find the docs at: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html a bit lacking

Comment: this is basically the right idea. except that you want to use [`testbed.setup_env()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html#Changing_the_Default_Environment_Variables) instead of `os.environ` directly.