# How do I mock users with GAE and Nosetest?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nosetests, nose-gae

**How do I call call setup_env() when nose instantiates testbed on it's own?**

I'm trying to develop a App Engine app with TDD and I need to figure out how to mock users.

I start my tests with:
nosetests -v --with-gae

I had several people suggest using nosetests because it will make things easier.
However, all the examples for how to mock things seem to explicitly use testbed.setup_env()
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting
[How do you mock the User service in App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159396/how-do-you-mock-the-user-service-in-app-engine)

I don't understand how I can set environmental values using nosetests.

This is what I have now:

```
import sys, os, subprocess, time, unittest, shlex     
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")   
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/')     
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")      

os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'] = 'workout'   

from selenium import webdriver      
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  

from google.appengine.api import memcache, apiproxy_stub, apiproxy_stub_map     
from google.appengine.ext import db      
from google.appengine.ext import testbed      
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util       
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2      

class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):      
    # enable the datastore stub  
    nosegae_datastore_v3 = True  
    nosegae_datastore_v3_kwargs = {  
        'datastore_file': '/tmp/nosegae.sqlite3',  
        'use_sqlite': True  
    }  

    def setUp(self):      
        # Start the dev server    
       cmd = "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py /Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/workout_log/app.yaml --port 8080 --storage_path /tmp/datastore --clear_datastore --skip_sdk_update_check"    
       self.dev_appserver = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),     
                                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)    
       time.sleep(2) # Important, let dev_appserver start up    

       self.datastore_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('datastore_v3')    

       self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()      
       self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)      

    def tearDown(self):      
        self.browser.quit()        
        self.dev_appserver.terminate()
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: If I setUp with    tb = testbed.Testbed()
        tb.activate()   It doesn't work because nosetests sets up Testbed on it's own.

Comment: The SO post you link to tells you what you need.  It doesn't matter that you are using nose.  Nose is just a test runner so it doesn't change how you mock users in GAE.

Comment: So how do you call setup_env() when nose instantiates testbed on it's own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured this out myself.
I added the statement below to the test setUp():

```
testself.testbed.setup_env(user_is_admin='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can configure the users stub the same way you configure the datastore stub.

Here is an [example from the repo](https://github.com/Trii/NoseGAE/blob/master/examples/issue13-get_current_user/test.py#L9-L10)

Here are the [supported configuration keys](https://github.com/Trii/NoseGAE/blob/master/nosegae.py#L246-L249)

```
class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # enable the users stub
    nosegae_user = True
    nosegae_user_kwargs = {
        'USER_EMAIL': 'nosegae@example.org',
        'USER_IS_ADMIN': 1  # User should be considered an admin
    }
    # enable the datastore stub
    nosegae_datastore_v3 = True  
    nosegae_datastore_v3_kwargs = {  
        'datastore_file': '/tmp/nosegae.sqlite3',  
        'use_sqlite': True  
    }
```