# How to programmatically sign in to Google App Engine app for integration testing?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, redirect, automated-tests

I have an App Engine application that currently enforces authentication via the `login: admin` parameter in the route handlers in the application's `app.yaml` file. According to the [app.yaml documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_login), when setting a `login` value of anything other than `optional`:

> ...the handler first checks whether the user has signed in to the application using its authentication option. If not, by default, the user is redirected to the sign-in page.

This works fine for accessing the app through the GUI, as the user simply follows the redirect, signs in with his/her Google credentials and gets redirected back to the app.

But one of the app's integration tests makes a HTTP GET to one of the application's endpoints and asserts on the response. Because the `login: admin` setting redirects the request to the sign-in page, the assertion fails as it hasn't been authenticated.

As described in the docs:

> Once the user has signed in or created a Google account, the user is redirected back to your application.

My question is: how can I programmatically sign in to my Google account in my test code once the app has redirected the request to the sign-in page? Presumably, once this is done, the now-authenticated request will be redirected back to the app and all will be well.

UPDATE:

I came across [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101742/how-do-you-access-an-authenticated-google-app-engine-service-from-a-non-web-py?rq=1), but the accepted answer is from 2008 and uses Google's [now-defunct](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/client-login) ClientLogin API. [One of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813590/4929768) mentions using Google's OAuth support, but it isn't clear to me how I would use it for this case.

Comment: potentially of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159396/how-do-you-mock-the-user-service-in-app-engine

Comment: @DanCornilescu interesting, thanks. Unfortunately, this particular test is an integration test (it needs to make a request to the actual, deployed endpoint, with an actually authenticated user account). That would be useful for a unit test though.